# Move Up and Down Div with draggable effect dynamically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My page is displaying some div's which are dynamically created.

I want to make all div draggable so the user can easily change their position up and down. I just  want up and down position.

My code

```
if (@items.Data == true)
{
    <div class="@items.ShortDesc test1" id="@items.ShortDesc" >
   <input  type="text" class="txtbox" >

    </div>
}
```

I  am  using  jquery  Sort  its  working  fine  for  sort,  but  now  i  am  not  able  to  write  anything  on  my  textbox  which  are   in  div

So I want to change positions of my div by up and down.

Comment: i didn't  tried  anything  becoj  i  don't  have  any   idea  to  start.

Comment: have you seen this http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: yes  just  now  i  have  seen  let  me  test  first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: it  seems   to  be   what   i   need  is  this  work   with  dynamically  div's?

Comment: this  is  with  Ul  how  can   i  write  with  div

Answer (score 2):

there are many Solutions for this

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/08/explaining-jquery-sortables/

http://www.enfew.com/10-jquery-ui-sortable-tutorials-plugins-that-will-explain-everything-you-need-to-know/

http://www.xmech.net/programming/jquery-ui-sortable-tutorial/

Comment: ohh  jsfiddle    ok  i  ll  make  for  you

Comment: sorry that was my mistake (a java script syntax error) now its working now no need to jsfiddle. thanks